# AngularJS get current templateUrl (html page)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've used AngularJS to build my app. `ng-view` is set up with routing via the routeProvider.

It all works fine but I'd like to know how I can get the current templateUrl?

```
$routeProvider.
    when('/terms', {
                    templateUrl: '/pages/terms.html',
                    controller: AboutController
                   });
```

In this case `/pages/terms.html`...

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to know this ?

Comment: I'm integrating a CMS solution into my ASP.NET MVC site. The CMS essentially toggles contenteditable on tagged elements in the HTML thats been pulled in by Angular via template pages. Then "publish" sends the new HTML to my C# and it updates the HTML file on the server. But it needs to know which file to update. Simple!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're probably looking for `$route.current.templateUrl`.