# how do I find everything left of a certain character?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to get everything from the left of a `"/"` in a `templateURL` string from angular routing.

For example:

```
var app = angular.module('demoApp',  ['ngResource', 'ngRoute'], function ($routeProvider){   
    $routeProvider
        .when('/',{templateUrl: 'directoryName/pageName.html', controller: 'mainCtrl'});

});
```

Using `templateURL` property `"directoryName/pageName.html"` I would like to get `"directoryName"`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Where is your code and where is your string?

Comment: $routeProvider.when('/pageName.html', (templateURL: "directoryName/pageName.html', controller: "controllerName', 'page: 'pageName'))

Comment: I need to be able to grab directoryName for use in breadcrumbs.

Answer (score 2):

Use regex!

```
var regex = /([^\/]*)\//;
var stripped = regex.exec('#some/string/with/stuff')[1];
```

This gives you back `'#some'`

**EDIT**

As far as getting this in your code, you can use the `$routeChangeSuccess` event on $rootScope to get the route out and use that string somewhere else

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, current, previous) {
    // Use what @Dalorzo suggests
    var pathName = current.$$route.templateUrl.split('/')[0];
    // Do something with pathName ...
});
```

Comment: wouldn't `split` produce the same results? `'#some/string/with/stuff'.split('/')` btw this does not answer the question

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the regex solution. Isn't it possible to somehow grab the value of the templateURL parameter and use that?

Comment: `/^[^\/]*/.exec('#some/string/with/stuff')` does same thing without envolving arrays, and goes more specific about which part of the string should be looked at. Still, split should be a simplier solution.

Comment: All this sort of makes sense, but I don't have a clue how to actually implement it. I'm a serious angular newbie.

Can you elaborate a bit more please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `current` object of the `$route` service inside your controller to get the current route object. This way, to access the `templateUrl` property you just need to use : `$route.current.templateUrl`.

Now that you have this string, you can use `split('/')` on it to get a array of tokens inside the URL that are separated by a `/`.

Finally, to use it in your template, you just need to inject this value inside your `$scope`.

Comment: +1 For advising as this other similar post [How to get templateUrl](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13326994/1959948)